# One event function for array of comboboxes to change image source

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, events, combobox

can someone help me how to solve this.

I have a form with 4 triples: 2 combobox and 1 picture

- Need to change picture source as first+second combobox (combination of combobox values as picture file name .png)

How to name/id all of the comboboxes to get onchange event handling all of them? Which function can handle them all?

```
<form name="myform">

<select name="first" id="1" onchange="show();">
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
</select>
<select name="color" id="1" onchange="show();">
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
<img src="Dog-White.png">
<br/>

<select name="first" id="2" onchange="show();">
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
</select>
<select name="color" id="2" onchange="show();">
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
<img src="Cat-White.png">
<br/>

<select name="first" id="3" onchange="show();">
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
</select>
<select name="color" id="3" onchange="show();">
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
<img src="Dog-Black.png">
<br/>

<select name="first" id="4" onchange="show();">
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
</select>
<select name="color" id="4" onchange="show();">
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
<img src="Cat-Black.png">
<br/>

</form>
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique and should not start with a number. This is invalid HTML.

Comment: **Note:** IDs must be unique

Comment: For this event delegation is quite useful. You can assign a `change` event listener _to the `form`_ and check which one of these `selects` is equal to `e.target` and what its `.value` is and change the pictures accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

- You can't have same IDs to multiple elements.
- You should avoid using `<br/>`
- Avoid having so many event listners.

HTML Code:

```
<form class="myform">
<div>
<select name="first" class="imgsrcfirst">
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
</select>
<select name="color" class="imgsrccolor">
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
<img src="Dog-White.png">
</div>

<div>
<select name="first" class="imgsrcfirst">
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
</select>
<select name="color" class="imgsrccolor">
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
<img src="Cat-White.png">
</div>

<div>
<select name="first" class="imgsrcfirst">
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
</select>
<select name="color" class="imgsrccolor">
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
<img src="Dog-Black.png">
</div>

<div>
<select name="first" class="imgsrcfirst">
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
</select>
<select name="color" class="imgsrccolor">
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
<img src="Cat-Black.png">
</div>

</form>
```

jQuery Code:

```
 $('.myform .imgsrcfirst').change(function(){
           var $p = $(this).parent();
           $p.find('img').prop('src',$(this).val()+$p.find('.imgsrccolor').val()+'.png');

    });
 $('.myform .imgsrccolor').change(function(){
           var $p = $(this).parent();
           $p.find('img').prop('src',$p.find('.imgsrcfirst').val()+$(this).val()+'.png');

    });
```